# Showing dimension of a model in FreeCAD

Tags: autocad

I had a simple model imported into FreeCAD and I'd like to know the dimension of the bounding box for the model, how do I do that?

[image: Screenshot of a model in FreeCAD]

PS: the software used is `FreeCAD`, but the tag wasn't available.

Comment: Thats because CAD application use is not graphic design. Looks like a kuka robot. Maximum envelopes are described in a 2D drawing too.

Comment: @joojaa , sorry but the tag `autocad` is available. And what did you mean by: "Maximum envelopes are described in a 2D drawing too"

Comment: tags dont prove a thing anybody can add a tag. It is concievable that an autocad question could relate to graphic design say somebody wants to manufacture a sign.

Comment: which can also be done via freecad

Comment: Sure. But your not asking a graphic design question.

Comment: I think this would still be on topic though

Comment: Did you even read the tag description

Comment: yeah, it should be related to graphic design, and measurements are related. :-D

Comment: Onus is on you to prove this.

Comment: I don't find it necessary , if someone votes to close this, I think I will delete it. No need for too much discussion

Comment: My point is youd be better of closing this question and ask it in engineering

Comment: um... I'm just asking where the dimension showing button is, I'm not asking any maths, I mean , it's just related to the UI , but, I don't think I'm getting answers here, I asked the 3D printing folks, but no luck there as well

Comment: Like i said engineering.stackexchange anyway the is no show dimension button. Also consider this is the slowesttime of the year